# MySQL simple select - 15 second execution time - 7 Million Rows

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a mysql table with 7 Million rows (will grow by 10 million per month) of user traffic that I need to run real time analysis on. The table has multiple columns but I only need one in the result set.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT visitor 
FROM traffic 
WHERE `visited` < '2019-03-01' AND `client_id` = 1 AND `country` IS NOT NULL
```

This query takes 15 seconds to execute with 7 million rows currently. I have individual indexes on `visitor`, `visited`, `client_id`, and `country` as well as a composite index on [`visited`, `client_id` and `country`].

None of the indexes are unique, nor can they be.

Can you guys think of any way that I could the execution time of this query down?

Comment: Can you get an EXPLAIN for the query?

Comment: Optimal index for this query: `(client_id, visited [, visitor])`

Comment: Also try using a GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT : `SELECT visitor FROM traffic WHERE visited < '2019-03-01' AND client_id = 1 AND country IS NOT NULL GROUP BY visitor` It can be faster sometimes to use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT

Comment: Without EXPLAIN it's kind of hard to give you advices but maybe you can put a partition on visited by year

Comment: What is the type of visited?

Comment: Can you show us the index definitions?  It would be good to verify 1) that they are there, and 2) they were created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I will assume that visited is textual data, like varchar, because we see that client_id is numeric and in the case of country we are only interested to see whether it has a value. If the assumption that visited is textual is true, then the solution is to change its type to a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. Since it seems that we are not interested in time in this case, having a DATE column should be the hottest candidate.

The solution (make sure you have a transaction involved):

1. Create a temp_visited column into the table with the same type visited has
2. Copy the values visited has into temp_visited
3. Set visited values to null or remove the visited column (whatever you need)
4. Ensure that you have a visited column with a DATE type
5. Copy the values from temp_visited into visited by converting the textual values into DATE
6. Remove temp_visited column

Answer (score 0):

Data Warehousing often begs for summary tables.

That query (or rather a variant that hits the Summary Table) would run a lot faster if you built and maintained a Summary table with perhaps these columns:

- `visited` -- to the day (or month?)
- `country` -- maybe leaving out those without a country?
- `client_id`
- `visitor`
- `COUNT(*)`
- maybe `SUM()` of something?

As for `PARTITIONing`, it is probably useful *only* if you will be purging 'old' rows.

For the *current* query, the optimal index will be

```
INDEX(client_id, visited,   -- this much will be used in the `WHERE`
      country, visitor)     -- to make the index "covering"
```

Single-column indexes will be virtually useless.  My 4-col index will be significantly better than any 3-column index because of being 'covering'.  This means that the query can be run inside the index, and not have to reach over to the data's BTree.